# Sitecore publish pipeline, How to intercept content publish to web target using publish pipeline?

Tags: sitecore

When an item is published, before "Web" database picks it up, how can I write a pipeline so that I push the content to new target database and on successful publish to new target database, push the changes to "web" target database?

Any ideas or pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: Found this article : http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/08/intercept-item-publishing-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Comment: Why don't you just add an additional publish target? http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/02/how-to-add-new-publishing-target-in.html

Comment: Could you add a little more detail with what you're wanting to do? I'm not sure whether you'll be wanting to use a pipeline or an event.

Comment: I second @jammykam's comment. Sounds like you have a preview site and a live site. In which case you just need 2 publishing targets

Comment: Can you define what you mean with "on success"? Do you mean "success on publishing" or "succes on user acceptation"?

Comment: @jammykam and Martin Davies, I have added a processor to intercept the PerformAction processor and used  patch:before. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone add an answer to this, instead of a comment?